# Ruby - update hash keys to strip whitespaces

Tags: ruby

I would like to strip whitespaces from my hash, so if I have

```
{"my hash key": 12}
```

I would like to get

```
{"myhashkey": 12}
```

I have found some ways to strip from the values, but got a problem to do that on keys. When I tried

```
 my_hash.each_key{|k| k.gsub!(' ', '')}
```

I got the error:

```
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

and if use only gsub (without '!') it runs fine, but doesn't work.

So what's the best way to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code you'd tried for updating the hash keys.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keys in the hashes are frozen (as the error message says,) and hence they cannot be modified *inplace*. The new hash must be constructed with new keys:

```
{"my hash key" => 12}.map { |k, v| [k.delete(' '), v] }.to_h
#⇒ {"myhashkey"=>12}
```

**NB!** there is a pitfall: you might lose some values!

```
{"a b c" => 42, "abc" => :foo}.
  map { |k, v| [k.delete(' '), v] }.to_h
#⇒ {"abc"=>:foo}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna accept the answer as soon as I can =)

Comment: Thanks for the warning! But in my case that's not gonna happen

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`transform_keys`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys):

```
my_hash = { 'my hash key': 12 }
#=> {:"my hash key"=>12}

my_hash.transform_keys { |k| k.to_s.delete(' ').to_sym }
#=> {:myhashkey=>12}
```

The `to_s` / `to_sym` conversion is needed because `Symbol` doesn't implement `delete`. You can omit it if your keys are actually strings:

```
my_hash = { 'my hash key' => 12 }
#=> {:"my hash key"=>12}

my_hash.transform_keys { |k| k.delete(' ') }
#=> {:myhashkey=>12}
```

Comment: I've wondered if you'd ever change your avatar. I don't recall the grey hair.

Comment: Holy Moly!! +1 to @CarySwoveland

Comment: @CarySwoveland only once in a blue moon ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
h = { "my hash key": 12 }
h.map {|key, value| [key.to_s.delete(' '), value] }.to_h
```

Basically, you map your hash to a new array where you strip all white spaces (that's what the `key.to_s.delete(' ')` does), and you convert it back to a hash with `.to_h` :)

**EDIT**

Just saw @stephen's answer, which uses `transform_keys`, a much simpler method which was introduced in Ruby 2.5.

However I'm still gonna leave my answer up, in case anyone using a previous version of Ruby stumbles upon this